# css sibling selectors. Target sibling element from element with a specific tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am currently trying to target a specific element on my mobile site. The software package we are using locks down the HTML code, so I am unable to add any classes or ID tags. However, I feel that it is possible to target the speicific element I am after.

My problem is I am attempting to target the `<nav>` element on a page, based on the value given to an adjacent UL with a specific title tag. Here is the current code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <nav id="navigationWrapper"></nav>
        <ul id="home" title="Home"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this particular instance, the `title="Home"` portion of the code changes based on which page the user is currently viewing. The title tag of the current page is applied.

My hope is to be able to somehow target the `<nav>` element on just the home page, based on the dynamic value given to the "title=" portion of the sibiling ul element. Is this possible?

I've tried what I thought would work `#navigationWrapper + ul[title="Home"]`, but it does not.

Comment: Are you allowed to use javascript at all?

Comment: It would appear that I am not able to :(

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot (with the exception of `:last…` pseudo-classes) select an element based on what comes after it in the document.